# Running Ejabberd Deis/Docker

Tags: docker, ejabberd, deis

I'm trying to deploy a [rroemhild/ejabberd](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/rroemhild/ejabberd/) container using [Deis](http://deis.io/). No errors are listed during the launch process, but when i access the ports 5280 (http) and 4560 (xmlrpc) there are no response.

Deis is running in a AWS and i'm trying to access from my home.

Comment: if the container exposes more than one port, you're going to hit https://github.com/deis/deis/issues/1156.